# how solve "unfortunately android app has stopped"

Tags: android

I made app for shoutcast stream and work good but when I stop it and go back by back button 
this message appear `unfortunately android app has stopped` and this my code i want to close the app when i stop it by stop button and when press back button close do not unfortunately android app has stopped

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button startButton, stopButton;
    static Context context;
    boolean isPlaying;
    Intent streamService;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    // headset
    private int headsetSwitch = 1 ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        getPrefs();
        streamService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StreamService.class);     

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startService(streamService);
                startButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                stopService(streamService);
                startButton.setEnabled(true);

                //headset2
                registerReceiver(headsetReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG));



            }
        });
    }


    // If headset gets unplugged, stop music and service.
    private BroadcastReceiver headsetReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        private boolean headsetConnected = false;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Log.v(TAG, "ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG Intent received");
            if (intent.hasExtra("state")) {
                if (headsetConnected && intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 0) {
                    headsetConnected = false;
                    headsetSwitch = 0;
                    // Log.v(TAG, "State =  Headset disconnected");
                    // headsetDisconnected();
                } else if (!headsetConnected
                        && intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 1) {
                    headsetConnected = true;
                    headsetSwitch = 1;
                    // Log.v(TAG, "State =  Headset connected");
                }

            }

            switch (headsetSwitch) {
            case (0):
                headsetDisconnected();
                break;
            case (1):
                break;
            }
        }

    };

    private void headsetDisconnected() {
        stopService(streamService);
        startButton.setEnabled(true);

    }


    public void getPrefs() {
            isPlaying = prefs.getBoolean("isPlaying", false);
            if (isPlaying) startButton.setEnabled(false);

            PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                    if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                        //Incoming call: Pause music
                        stopService(streamService);
                        startButton.setEnabled(true);
                    } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        //Not in call: Play music
                        startService(streamService);
                        startButton.setEnabled(false);
                    } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                        //A call is dialing, active or on hold
                        stopService(streamService);
                        startButton.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                }
            };
            TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if(mgr != null) {
                mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            }

    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopService(streamService);
        startButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

```
08-06 13:12:25.519: D/StreamService(22065): onDestroy
08-06 13:12:25.519: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(22065): stop
08-06 13:12:25.519: V/MediaPlayer(22065): stop
08-06 13:12:25.529: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(22065): release
08-06 13:12:25.529: V/MediaPlayer(22065): setListener
08-06 13:12:25.529: V/MediaPlayer(22065): disconnect
08-06 13:12:25.539: V/MediaPlayer(22065): destructor
08-06 13:12:25.539: V/MediaPlayer(22065): disconnect
08-06 13:12:26.624: D/AndroidRuntime(22039): Shutting down VM
08-06 13:12:26.624: W/dalvikvm(22039): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d44700)
08-06 13:12:26.629: E/AndroidRuntime(22039): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 13:12:26.629: E/AndroidRuntime(22039): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.test.test/com.test.test.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onDestroy()
08-06 13:12:26.629: E/AndroidRuntime(22039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3621)
08-06 13:12:26.629: E/AndroidRuntime(22039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3654)
08-06 13:12:26.629: E/AndroidRuntime(22039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:159)
08-06 13:12:26.629: E/AndroidRuntime(22039):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
08-06 13:12:26.629: E/AndroidRuntime(22039):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 13:12:26.629: E/AndroidRuntime(22039):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
08-06 13:12:26.629: E/AndroidRuntime(22039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
08-06 13:12:26.629: E/AndroidRuntime(22039):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 13:12:26.629: E/AndroidRuntime(22039):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-06 13:12:26.629: E/AndroidRuntime(22039):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
08-06 13:12:26.629: E/AndroidRuntime(22039):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
08-06 13:12:26.629: E/AndroidRuntime(22039):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Start with the exception stacktrace in logcat. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: in your **onDestroy()** what this **startButton.setEnabled(true);** thing is doing?

Comment: +1 to @ laalto **and also** why is your onDestroy() not overriden?

Comment: It is the shape of buttom

Comment: @MohamedElsayed The truth has been spoken :)

Comment: :) i am  new android developer and i am training but this message apear

Comment: the error in @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
  stopService(streamService);
  startButton.setEnabled(true);
  finish();
 }
but i wanna when destroy the activity close the program

Comment: post your logcat and your latest code, please.. and what is the error message?

Comment: i post it im main code up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your logcat:

```
android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.test.test/com.test.test.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onDestroy()
```

Add `super.onDestroy()` to your overridden `onDestroy()` method.

> when i press back buttom the app closed and i do not want that

You can override `onBackPressed()` in your activity and **not** call `super.onBackPressed()` or `finish()` there to prevent the back key from finishing your activity. Though usually it's a bad idea to make your app behave not according to user expectations.

Comment: i do it and the message dosenot appear but when i press back buttom the app closed and i do not want that

Comment: i wanna stop app only when press back butom only if the stram off and if is on and press back buttom i want it to still work

Comment: You can write the logic in `onBackPressed()`. Call `finish()` when in fact you want to finish the activity.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
super.onDestroy();
```

on your onDestroy method

Comment: it work and the message does not appear but when press back buttom the app closed

Comment: if you want to close app @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
finish();
    } otherwise remove finish();

Comment: yes i want to close app when i press back butoom but only when the player off but if is working and press back buttom i want to still work

Comment: so check with condition if not playing then finish(); otherwise not

Answer (score 0):

```
  Just override onbackpressed method 
stop everything here and close activity.

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
finish();
    }
```

Comment: can you send me logcat of crash.

Comment: the error in onDestroy but i wanna when close activity close the program but it restart

Comment: After call finish(); that activity should be close.